# Can't add a div using javascript where cakephp is used

Tags: javascript, cakephp-2.0

I am working with cakephp.

I want to add a `<div>` dynamically each time I press a button. My code works if I don't add `array("type"=>"select"));`

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'dataN' ;
div.innerHTML='<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"      style="text-align: left;"></table>\n\
<tr>\n\
<td width="150px" style="text-align:center;background:#D9D9D9;">Step 1-Select Program Country </td>\n\
<td width="250px" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php echo $this->form->input("Proposal.program_country", array("type"=>"select")); ?></td></tr>\n\
</tr>';
document.getElementById('data').appendChild(div);
```

Comment: What are you seeing after clicking the button? Is it adding a DIV without the country dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `"type" => "select"` to `"options" => array()`? Have not seen any other way to create a select tag in CakePHP 2.x form helper other than this one.

Please refer to this part of the [CookBook](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#common-options).